# When we copy a file of size 'X' GB, who/what holds the copied 'X' GB memory?

Tags: memory, copy

when we copy a file, of size 'X' GB, from folder A to folder B. what holds that 'X' GB file until i go to folder B and say paste?

Comment: probably nothing, it might just remember the path you copied to the clipboard, not the file contents itself. Also, please specify the 'Copy & Paste' software you are using (e.g. Explorer by Windows 7)

Comment: Thanks for the response. i am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you right click a file and choose `Copy`, the file explorer application will just remember that you copied something. *Nothing* is done until you actually click `Paste`, when it starts cloning the last file on which you clicked `Copy`, to the target folder.